# What is the discarding algorithm in Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

So in a question, I am given 5 vectors. Then I am asked to find the 3 linearly independent vectors out of the set using "the discarding algorithm".

This is explained briefly but terribly in my professor's notes and I can't find anything on the internet about "the discarding algorithm". I go to an Italian university so maybe it's a bad translation.

I do know how to find the linearly independent vectors by putting them into a matrix and row reducing and whatnot. But the question specifically asked to use "the discarding algorithm". As far as I can tell, these are two different techniques, so I'm really confused.

If anyone could explain it to me or reference a website or something I would be hugely grateful!

Comment: Perhaps you should add the “brief but terrible” explanation from your professor so that we get an idea what this is about.

Comment: Hint: in a linearly dependent set, some of the vectors are linear combinations of the others. Throw away (ahem, discard) the redundant ones.

Comment: Reference- Friedberg, Stephen  H., Insel, Arnold J., & Spence, Lawrence E., Linear Algebra and its Applications, 4th Edition, Theorem 1.9 and Example-6, Page- 44-45

Comment: Thank you for the replies. It turned out to be quite simple. I should've understood it better just by it's name.